# How to increase string length using Log4j2 JsonTemplate Layout

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

By referring ([JsonTemplateLayout Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#event-template-resolvers)) I am trying to increase the length of the message as I am getting ... in the logs.
In the link, it's mentioned to use property maxStringLength.

I have tried to add it in 2 ways:

1. added in log4j2-spring

   ```
   <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:log4j2_JsonEventLayout.json"            
           locationInfoEnabled="true" maxStringLength="30000">
   </JsonTemplateLayout>
   ```
2. added in JsonEvenLayout file

   ```
   "message": {
       "$resolver": "message",
       "stringified": true,
       "maxStringLength":30000
   }
   ```

but both didn't work.

Comment: I did the first step of those you've provided and it works without changing the `JsonEventLayout` file.

Comment: Yes it worked later..